# Advice on UK Based Dedicated Server / VPS Hosting Companies Required - Price / Customer Service / Specs

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I know this seems like a simple question, but I'm struggling to work out who is going to be a decent UK based web host for my next project. It's hard to know which "review" sites are not being paid, there is no consistency between them.

I'm not exactly new to this, I have rented hosting packages from various companies before, (though not for a couple of years now), and worked in enough companies to know what spec of server I need (Ideally dedicated server). What I'm more interested in is value for money and decent customer service.

Ideally I'd like a lowish powered dedicated server. Maybe a couple of processors, 2GB ram and 100+ GB disk space.

I've used EUKHost a couple of times before, and found them good customer service level wise. However looking now, they seem a bit pricey for the spec of the servers they are offering, especially when compared with 1 & 1.

Still, I'm not sure about going with such a huge company like 1 & 1 as the customer service level suffers I believe.

I've also approached RackSpace, but their pricing is less than clear, and it seems not that competitive.

Is there a current market leader that wins on all fronts that any one can recommend?

As I say, I've been out of this game for a while! Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Closing this as "Too Localised", this is essentially a shopping question, which the [Stack Exchange engine is not designed for](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [Melbourne](http://www.melbourne.co.uk/).co.uk at work for a dedicated server solution.  They're very good.  Reasonably priced, intelligent support staff, and a variety of  configurable server options at purchase time, as well as easy upgrades.

I don't work for them, but I'd be happy to use their services again / recommend them.